# New laptop, how do I connect my Github with my new command prompter?

Tags: git, github

Basically, how do I authenticate my new laptop to connect to my GitHub account!?

Comment: If you are using OSX you can log in with iTerm or OhMyZSH and have the credentials saved in the keychain: 
$ git credential-osxkeychain erase
host=github.com
protocol=https
> [Press Return]

Comment: Have you checked the docs? [Connecting to GitHub with SSH](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, using [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), you would:

- [generate an SSH key (Windows instruction)](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) and [register the public key to your GitHub account](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)
- make sure `git config --global credential.helper` is set to `manager`: that will allow you to cache (on first push using an HTTPS URL `https://github.com/...`) your username/password.
  Note that if you have [2FA activated on GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa), you will need to generate a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line), and use that token as your password.